# Problem with initializing user while installing MySQL Server

Tags: software-installation, symlink, mysql

I'm trying to install my first community MySQL server instance and seems to be stuck on symlink not working. I'm following the procedure for installing MySQLfrom [Installing MySQL on Unix/Linux Using Generic Binaries](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/binary-installation.html).

OSVersion: RHEL 7
MySQLVersion:   8

The executable binary is sitting in following folder:

```
/usr/local/mysql-8.0.19-linux-glibc2.12-x86_64
```

I created symlink via this command:

```
pwd
/usr/local
sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql-8.0.3-rc-linux-glibc2.12-x86_64 /usr/local/mysql
cd mysql
```

and ran this command to initialize user with ./ and / nothing seems to work.

```
-bash-4.2$ ./bin/mysqld --initialize --user=mysql
-bash: ./bin/mysqld: No such file or directory
-bash-4.2$ /bin/mysqld --initialize --user=mysql
-bash: /bin/mysqld: No such file or directory
-bash-4.2$
```

Here's how the symlink is looking:
[image]

I wonder where am I wrong? Any guidance would be appreciated as I'm stuck with this issue since yesterday.

Tried this and it didn't worked either:

```
    -bash-4.2$ export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin
    -bash-4.2$ echo $PATH
    /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin
    -bash-4.2$ mysqld --initialize --user=mysql
    -bash: mysqld: command not found
    -bash-4.2$
    -bash-4.2$ sudo ./bin/mysqld --initialize --user=mysql
     Command not found
    -bash-4.2$
    -bash-4.2$ sudo ./mysqld --initialize --user=mysql
     Command not found
    -bash-4.2$
```

Comment: A far easier way to do this is to add the MySQL repo and install it that way. You haven't stated which distro that you are using, but if it's RHEL 8, CentOS 8 or Ubuntu 19, MySQL 8 is in the regular repos.

Comment: @NasirRiley Repo is not an option as the server is not connected to the internet. I will update the question with OS Version.

Comment: You can download the RPMs and put them on the machine in the same way that you got the other files on the machine and then install them.

Comment: @NasirRiley, I was indeed thinking of going that route but wanted to see if I can find out if I can troubleshoot this issue. I think here the installation is not the main issue but symlink is causing trouble as the commands are unable to read from the source and I'm not sure what is causing it. I created the symlink by providing the full path and it should work.

Comment: In the time that you've waited for a way to fix it, you could have download the RPMs, put them on the machine, and installed them.

Comment: The path to use is displayed on screen, isn't it?

Comment: @MartinZeitler Sorry for my rookiness which path are you talking about?

Comment: @Ali Have added an answer, explaining what I believe that might be the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

You might have missed the last one instruction, where it is being added into the `$PATH`:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

This goes into file `~/.bashrc`.

Because then one can simply call it directly (at least after a reboot):

```
mysqld --initialize --user=mysql
```

... which then resolves to:

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld --initialize --user=mysql
```

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. Added the commands at the end of my question and the output. Rebooted the system as well.

Comment: Also as an fyi, when I'm logged in as mysql user then I can't seem to find the .bashrc file but when I sudo as root I can cat the .bashrc file. 
 cat .bashrc
# .bashrc

# User specific aliases and functions

alias rm='rm -i'
alias cp='cp -i'
alias mv='mv -i'

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bashrc
fi

Comment: @Ali obviously you should login as `root` or prefix the input with `sudo`. The instructions probably do not state at all to login as `mysql` and this user usually should not even have a login shell. If it really should be that difficult for you, just follow the above suggestion and download the RPM to an USB stick.

Comment: yes I tried as root as well and I still can't get through this issue exactly the same issue.